# How to change wl.client.init in IBM MobileFirst version 8

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I an trying to convert my MFP 7.1 hybrid app to MFP v8 Cordova app .However, I am getting an error with the statement 'WL.init.connect'.

What is strange is that I am able to deploy the app in MobileFirst version 8 and run it my device. I see the device ID in the operation console. So, it is connecting to MobileFirst with the current code

Can you please take a look at the code snippet and give me some hint on how to make the necessary changes.

Information
Cordova version 6.3.1
MFP- 8.0.0-2016080322

### Code myWorklight.js

```
 (function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('my-worklight', [])
    .run(WorklightRun)
  WorklightRun.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$q'];

  /**
   * Load worklight
   */
  function WorklightRun($rootScope, $q) {
    // Worklight statuss
    var initDeferred = $q.defer();
    $rootScope.worklightInitPromise = initDeferred.promise;
    $rootScope.worklightLoaded = false;
    var connectionDeferred = $q.defer();
    $rootScope.worklightConnectionPromise = connectionDeferred.promise;
    $rootScope.worklightConnected = false;
    // Listen for load / onload and start worklight init
    if (window.addEventListener) {
      //alert('calling LOAD window.addEventListener');
      window.addEventListener('load', loadHandler, false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
        //alert('calling LOAD window.attachEvent');
      window.attachEvent('onload', loadHandler);
    }

    // Worklight connect options
    var wlConnectOptions = {
      timeout: 10000,
      onFailure: connectionFailure,
      onSuccess: function () {
        console.log('MFP: Connected');
        $rootScope.worklightConnected = true;
        connectionDeferred.resolve();
      }
    };
    // Worklight init options
    var wlInitOptions = {
      timeout: 10000,
      onConnectionFailure: initFailure,
      onFailure: initFailure,
      onSuccess: function () {
        console.log('MFP: Loaded');
        initDeferred.resolve();
        $rootScope.worklightLoaded = true;
        if (window.addEventListener) {
          window.addEventListener(WL.Events.WORKLIGHT_IS_CONNECTED, wlConnectedHandler, true);
          window.addEventListener(WL.Events.WORKLIGHT_IS_DISCONNECTED, wlDisconnectedHandler, true);
        } else if (window.attachEvent) {
          window.attachEvent(WL.Events.WORKLIGHT_IS_CONNECTED, wlConnectedHandler);
          window.attachEvent(WL.Events.WORKLIGHT_IS_DISCONNECTED, wlDisconnectedHandler);
        }
        console.log('MFP: About to connect - ' + JSON.stringify(wlConnectOptions, null, 2));
        WL.Client.connect(wlConnectOptions);
      }
    };

    var worklightLoadEvent = null;
    worklightLoadEvent = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');

    function loadHandler() {
      try {
        console.log('MFP: Load event detected, about to init - ' + JSON.stringify(wlInitOptions, null, 2));
        WL.Client.init(wlInitOptions);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('MFP: "WL" init error - ' + err);
        initFailure(err);
        worklightLoadEvent.initCustomEvent('worklightLoadFailure', true, false, {});
        window.dispatchEvent(worklightLoadEvent);
      }
    }

    function wlConnectedHandler() {
      $rootScope.worklightConnected = true;
        navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    }

    function wlDisconnectedHandler() {
      $rootScope.worklightFailureAcknowledged = true;
      $rootScope.worklightConnected = false;
        navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    }

    function connectionFailure(err) {
      console.log('MFP: No Connection - ' + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
      connectionDeferred.reject(err);
    }

    function initFailure (err) {
      console.log('MFP: init failed - ' + err);
      initDeferred.reject(err);
      connectionFailure(err);
    }

  }
})();
```

I include this file in my app.js file.. So, it is getting run first...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

In v8.0, many features and APIs have either been deprecated or discontinued. You need to review this list of API changes and make your changes accordingly.

- Migration cookbook: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/migration-cookbook/
- Deprecated features and APIs: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/what_s_new/c_deprecations.html
- Discontinued features and APIs: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/what_s_new/c_removed_features.html

Also review release notes, known issues and so on: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/start/c_release_notes.html

Comment: Thanks.. I did review the document but I am stuck on how to get pass this issue.  Basically, how  do i connect to MobileFirst without using the wl.client.init and wl.client.connect...  Thanks for the additional  help

Comment: In v8.0 you're not supposed to use either... you're supposed to obtain a tile only when you want to access a resource. I suggest to again review the APIs.

Comment: ok.. I will review the document again.. but I am not sure why it seems to works in 8.0.. meaning that my device is getting register...

Comment: Do you have sample of an angular application connecting to MobileFirst?.

Comment: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/08/11/best-practices-for-building-angularjs-apps-with-mobilefirst-foundation-8.0/

Answer (score 0):

You can something like the following:

```
function isServerReachable() {                                          
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){                          
     WL.App.getServerUrl(function(endpoint){                            
       var req = new WLResourceRequest(endpoint + '/reach//',           
       WLResourceRequest.GET);                                          
       req.send().then(resolve, reject);                                
     }, reject);                                                        
 });                                                                    
}
```

Then you can call it:

```
isServerReachable().then(function(response){                            
  // connected to server                               
}).catch(function(error){                                               
  // error reaching the server                                          
})
```